# Show variables or some info in Scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, cucumber, bdd

I want to show variable values in console while my scenario performing. Cause I don`t know how to know it in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logger.debug(whatever)
puts whatever
binding.pry # Links below
```

[Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [Rails and Pry](https://gist.github.com/941174)

Or ruby debugger, or debug inside an IDE, or...